# Parallel processing from a command queue on Linux (bash, python, ruby... whatever)

Tags: python, ruby, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have a list/queue of 200 commands that I need to run in a shell on a Linux server.

I only want to have a maximum of 10 processes running (from the queue) at once. Some processes will take a few seconds to complete, other processes will take much longer.

When a process finishes I want the next command to be "popped" from the queue and executed.

Does anyone have code to solve this problem?

**Further elaboration:**

There's 200 pieces of work that need to be done, in a queue of some sort. I want to have at most 10 pieces of work going on at once. When a thread finishes a piece of work it should ask the queue for the next piece of work. If there's no more work in the queue, the thread should die. When all the threads have died it means all the work has been done.

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is using `imapsync` to synchronize 200 mailboxes from an old mail server to a new mail server. Some users have large mailboxes and take a long time tto sync, others have very small mailboxes and sync quickly.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would imagine you could do this using make and the make -j xx command.

Perhaps a makefile like this

```
all : usera userb userc....

usera:
       imapsync usera
userb:
       imapsync userb
....
```

make -j 10 -f makefile

Comment: This worked exactly as I hoped it would. I wrote some code to generate the Makefile. It ended up being over 1000 lines. Thanks!

Comment: I found that if any of the commands exits with an error code, make will exit, preventing execution of future jobs.  In some situations, this solution is less than ideal. Any recommendations for this scenario?

Comment: @redmoskito If you run make with the "-k" option it will keep running even if there are errors.

Comment: if one starts thinking of make not as "task scheduler" but as of "parallel compilation" tool.. I guess the bigger picture is that 'make -j' respects dependencies, which makes this solution mind blowing once applied universally.

Answer (score 47):

On the shell, `xargs` can be used to queue parallel command processing. For example, for having always 3 sleeps in parallel, sleeping for 1 second each, and executing 10 sleeps in total do

```
echo {1..10} | xargs -d ' ' -n1 -P3 sh -c 'sleep 1s' _
```

And it would sleep for 4 seconds in total. If you have a list of names, and want to pass the names to commands executed, again executing 3 commands in parallel, do

```
cat names | xargs -n1 -P3 process_name
```

Would execute the command `process_name alice`, `process_name bob` and so on.

Comment: Wow, I use `xargs` all the time and never expected it would have this option!

Comment: For the second example you give, how do you modify the command so that `process_name` can take more than one argument? I want to do something like this: `cat commands.txt | xargs -n1 -P3 eval` where `commands.txt` has a bunch of commands in it (one on each line, each with multiple arguments). The problem is that `eval` doesn't work as it's a shell builtin command

Comment: @Eddy try using a shell as the program to run; this allows you to use arbitrary shell commands as the inputs.  The first answer above does this with `sh`, but you can do it with `bash` as well.  E.g. if your `commands.txt` has a bunch of lines in it that look like `echo test1; sleep1`, you can use that via something like `cat commands.txt | xargs -d'\n' -P3 -n1 /bin/bash -c`

Answer (score 29):

[Parallel](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/parallel/) is made exatcly for this purpose.

```
cat userlist | parallel imapsync
```

One of the beauties of [Parallel](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/parallel/) compared to other solutions is that it makes sure output is not mixed. Doing `traceroute` in [Parallel](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/parallel/) works fine for example:

```
(echo foss.org.my; echo www.debian.org; echo www.freenetproject.org) | parallel traceroute
```

Comment: Man I love this tool. I've known about it for like 3h and I am going to use it until the very stones of the earth cry out for me to stop.

Comment: Fedora 16 included the tool into package repository

Answer (score 13):

For this kind of job PPSS is written: Parallel processing shell script. Google for this name and you will find it, I won't linkspam.

Comment: This looks ideal. I'll check it out next time I'm faced with a similar problem. Thanks for updating this thread with your recommendation.

Comment: awesome! can we set it up dynamic threading that e.g. 80% CPU/Ram allow ?

Comment: Almost exactly what I was looking for. /me goes back to struggling to get it working.

Answer (score 7):

GNU make (and perhaps other implementations as well) has the -j argument, which governs how many jobs it will run at once. When a job completes, make will start another one.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if they are largely independent of each other, I'd think in terms of:

```
Initialize an array of jobs pending (queue, ...) - 200 entries
Initialize an array of jobs running - empty

while (jobs still pending and queue of jobs running still has space)
    take a job off the pending queue
    launch it in background
    if (queue of jobs running is full)
        wait for a job to finish
        remove from jobs running queue
while (queue of jobs is not empty)
    wait for job to finish
    remove from jobs running queue
```

Note that the tail test in the main loop means that if the 'jobs running queue' has space when the while loop iterates - preventing premature termination of the loop.  I think the logic is sound.

I can see how to do that in C fairly easily - it wouldn't be all that hard in Perl, either (and therefore not too hard in the other scripting languages - Python, Ruby, Tcl, etc).  I'm not at all sure I'd want to do it in shell - the `wait` command in shell waits for all children to terminate, rather than for some child to terminate.

Comment: you can use the wait command for a specific child process too.  It can be given any number of arguments, each of which  can be a pid or job id.

Comment: @BrianMinton: you're right that you can list specific PIDs with `wait`, but you still get the 'all of them dead' behaviour, not 'first one dead' which is what this code really needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use Python, I recommend using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for this.

Specifically [Twisted Runner](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedRunner).

Answer (score 3):

In python, you could try:

```
import Queue, os, threading

# synchronised queue
queue = Queue.Queue(0)    # 0 means no maximum size

# do stuff to initialise queue with strings
# representing os commands
queue.put('sleep 10')
queue.put('echo Sleeping..')
# etc
# or use python to generate commands, e.g.
# for username in ['joe', 'bob', 'fred']:
#    queue.put('imapsync %s' % username)

def go():
  while True:
    try:
      # False here means no blocking: raise exception if queue empty
      command = queue.get(False)
      # Run command.  python also has subprocess module which is more
      # featureful but I am not very familiar with it.
      # os.system is easy :-)
      os.system(command)
    except Queue.Empty:
      return

for i in range(10):   # change this to run more/fewer threads
  threading.Thread(target=go).start()
```

Untested...

(of course, python itself is single-threaded.  You should still get the benefit of multiple threads in terms of waiting for IO, though.)

Comment: 1) os.system could be replaced with the new improved subprocess module.
2) It doesn't matter that CPython has a GIL because you're running external commands, not Python code (functions).

Comment: If you replace `threading.Thread` by `multiprocessing.Process` and `Queue` by `multiprocessing.Queue` then the code will run using multiple processes.

Comment: pssh is written in python I think

Answer (score 2):

https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel (gnu parallel)
and pssh might help.

Answer (score 1):

Python's [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) would seem to fit your issue nicely.  It's a high-level package that supports threading by process.

Answer (score 0):

Simple function in zsh to parallelize jobs in not more than 4 subshells, using lock files in /tmp.

The only non trivial part are the glob flags in the first test:

- `#q`: enable filename globbing in a test
- `[4]`: returns the 4th result only
- `N`: ignore error on empty result

It should be easy to convert it to posix, though it would be a bit more verbose.

Do not forget to escape any quotes in the jobs with `\"`.

```
#!/bin/zsh

setopt extendedglob

para() {
    lock=/tmp/para_$$_$((paracnt++))
    # sleep as long as the 4th lock file exists
    until [[ -z /tmp/para_$$_*(#q[4]N) ]] { sleep 0.1 }
    # Launch the job in a subshell
    ( touch $lock ; eval $* ; rm $lock ) &
    # Wait for subshell start and lock creation
    until [[ -f $lock ]] { sleep 0.001 }
}

para "print A0; sleep 1; print Z0"
para "print A1; sleep 2; print Z1"
para "print A2; sleep 3; print Z2"
para "print A3; sleep 4; print Z3"
para "print A4; sleep 3; print Z4"
para "print A5; sleep 2; print Z5"

# wait for all subshells to terminate
wait
```

Answer (score -3):

Can you elaborate what you mean by *in parallel*? It sounds like you need to implement some sort of locking in the queue so your entries are not selected twice, etc and the commands run only once.

Most queue systems cheat -- they just write a giant to-do list, then select e.g. ten items, work them, and select the next ten items. There's no parallelization.

If you provide some more details, I'm sure we can help you out.