# How to speed up through-put of "find . -type f -size +0 -exec ./work.sh {} \;"

Tags: bash, sed, find

When calling the following command I found that it runs slowly despite neither disk nor CPU nor memory being consumed too much (checked with top / iotop)

```
find . -type f -size +0 -exec ./work.sh {} \;
```

I chose this particular find construct because I have a lot of files (>50k).

inside work.sh is basically like this:

```
prefix=\"$filename\"";"\"$timestamp\"";"\"
SED_ARG="-e 's/^/"$prefix"/'"
zcat $1 | sed = | sed 'N;s/\n/";/' | grep -vE '"timepassed";' | eval sed "$SED_ARG" >> $logfilename
```

What would be ways to profile or improve performance? I was maybe find waits for exec to return on each file while it could just spawn the next exec for the next file.

Comment: What is `"$SED_ARG"`?

Comment: I edited the question to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

partition the job into chunks and run them using shell job control.  Or install GNU parallel if this is going to be an everyday thing.  job control example:

```
cnt=1
find . -type f -size +0 |
while read fname 
do
   zcat $fname | sed = | sed 'N;s/\n/";/' | grep -vE '"timepassed";' | 
             eval sed "$SED_ARG" >> $logfilename &
   [ $(( $cnt % 10  )) -eq 0 ] && wait
   cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
done
wait
```

This runs ten jobs at a time.  Change the 10 to suit your system, a higher number is NOT always a better choice.

$(( % ))  is modulo - remainder - arithmetic.  So when cnt is 10 20 30 ...  $(( $cnt % 10 ))
returns zero. Everytime the value returns zero the script calls wait. The last wait statement (below the word done) is there incase tthe loop ends on a number than is not evenly divisible by 10, e.g. 52002.  This is all part of bash.

Comment: This looks good, could comment how this  [ $(( $cnt % 10  )) -eq 0 ] && part works? when is the counter ever reduced? Also why the wait after the loop?

Comment: This gives a few alternatives to parallels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463963/parallel-processing-from-a-command-queue-on-linux-bash-python-ruby-whateve

Comment: Why would you do anything but add? You are counting from 1 to 50,000. Every tenth time you then wait for your 10 jobs to complete.

Comment: Sorry that I can't follow yet, can this be run from bash? how does the $cnt % 10 part realize that the 1-10 previous jobs are all done?

Comment: This reduced the time by 50% slightly faster than xargs -P10

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason your execution is slow because you have too many piped commands. If I understood correctly your chain of piped commands can be **greatly refactored** to this:

```
zcat $1 | awk -v f="$filename" -v t="$timestamp" '$1 !~ "\"timepassed\";" {
             printf("\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%d\";%s\n", f, t, NR, $0)}' >> $logfilename
```

Once you verify that above code snippet is doing same job can you try your find command again to see the performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava that looks really good and so much easier to understand. Taught me well about awk. Unfortunately it is around 20% slower. Also I had to change the order of parameterss slightly to match my script I edited your answer.

Comment: To speedup we can avoid using awk regex `/"timepassed";/` since its not really a regex. Just want to know if this literal text `"timepassed";` can appear anywhere in a line or at the beginning?

Comment: It's save to assume it only happens at the beginning

Comment: I ran the second version but almost didn't affect performance, thanks for trying anubhava

Comment: Alright good to know, I edited it again accordingly. Pls try again.

Comment: I've tested again but no improvement, I use | xargs -P5 now with halfed the time. Thanks for your effort